# How to correctly implement repository level caching of data

Tags: c#, caching

What's the correct way to implement repository level caching of data? (This isn't about caching provider, it's about the relationship between cache and repository!)

Solution #1: Injected external simple cache

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IDataCache _dataCache;

    public MyRepository(IDataCache dataCache)
    {
        _dataCache = dataCache;
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var result = _dataCache.Get(id) as string;

        if (result == null)
        {
            //Go fetch data from data source
            _dataCache.Add(id, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Solution #2: Additional CachedRepository class implementing same interface
(this will require some funky DI configuration to resolve correctly, but it is possible)

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IDataCache _dataCache;

    public MyRepository(IDataCache dataCache)
    {
        _dataCache = dataCache;
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        //Go fetch data from data source
        return result;
    }
}

public class CachedMyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    private readonly IDataCache _dataCache;

    public CachedMyRepository(IMyRepository myRepository, IDataCache dataCache)
    {
        _dataCache = dataCache;
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var result = _dataCache.Get(id) as string;

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = _myRepository.Get(id);
            _dataCache.Add(id, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

(Each solution is based on this simple repository and cache interface for arguments sake)

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    string Get(int id);
}

public interface IDataCache
{
    object Get(object key);
    void Add(object key, object item);
}
```

Comment: Are you caching some object that will never change its state? When are you going to invalidate your caches? Looks like never to me from IDataCache interface.

Comment: Mc Kevin. You're missing the point. This isn't about cache implementation, this is about the relationship between the repository and the cache. Read the question please.

Comment: Solution 2 looks better to me, I think you don't need IDataCache in MyRepository for Solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't say there's a strictly "correct" way here. You have to consider the implications of each design and see what better fits your specific scenario.

The first option makes your repository conceptually a caching repository, in the sense that it requires an IDataCache to work (at least, that's what the design implies). You can probably use the Null Object pattern to support turning caching on and off. If testing is an important consideration for you, then in this case you need to either use a test double of some kind, or you can test the repository and data cache together.

The second option is essentially the Decorator pattern (except that you don't need the IDataCache into MyRepository - I assume this is due to copy-pasting). It makes your repository completely oblivious to any caching logic. There is potential to dynamically add and remove caching, and you can also augment your repository with other kinds of decorators (e.g. you could add logging). As for testing - you can test you repository as is, without any test doubles.

Comment: Solution #1 - let's assume there is no requirement to turn caching on or off, it's just always on.
Solution #2 - The reason the IDataCache has been abstracted is to make unit testing it possible without exposing a bunch of stuff AND to allow the instances of the CachedRepository/Repository to be transient/scoped as opposed to singleton.